# Global Replace Email Address With Perl

Tags: perl, email, string-interpolation

I try to use Perl to global replace the email address in my shell scripts but it seems Perl can not replace if there is @ character.

Part of my shell script:

```
MAIL_LIST_2="user01@abc.com"
```

The perl command:

```
perl -pi -e "s/user01@abc.com/user01@devemail.abc.com/g" test.sh
```

Any idea?

Comment: Also, instead of "_but it seems Perl can not..._" why not explain what that means (what happens?) and show any warnings and errors.  Warnings in one-liners can be enabled by `-w` swithc, so you'd have `perl -i -wpe'...'` (i like to separate the `-i` option)

Comment: While a script is not working, I recommend not using the `-i` option at all.  It can do damage to the file.  You're lucky that the changes were actually a no-op here.  When you're reasonably sure that the script does what you want, then you can add the `-i` option to make the changes in place.  Until then, don't include it.  This applies to other 'overwrite in place' programs such as `sed` too.  You can also use `perl -e '…' file | diff -u file -` to see what your script changes — as long as you aren't overwriting the file.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `@` sign in the email addresses in the Perl code:

```
echo 'MAIL_LIST_2="user01@abc.com"' |
perl -p -e "s/user01\@abc.com/user01\@devemail.abc.com/g"
```

which gives the output:

```
MAIL_LIST_2="user01@devemail.abc.com"
```

The problem is that Perl regards an unescaped `@` as the sigil for an array, and tries to interpolate the content of the (non-existent) arrays into the regex, which doesn't work as you want it to.

Note that if you enabled warnings — `-w` on the command line, or `use strict; use warnings;` in a script file — then you get told why things are not working so well:

```
echo 'MAIL_LIST_2="user01@abc.com"' |
perl -pwe "s/user01@abc.com/user01@devemail.abc.com/g"
Possible unintended interpolation of @abc in string at -e line 1.
Possible unintended interpolation of @devemail in string at -e line 1.
Name "main::abc" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Name "main::devemail" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
MAIL_LIST_2="user01@abc.com"
```

Moral: always enable warnings in Perl scripts — it avoids unnecessary pain.

Comment: You might include quotes in the regex substitution to avoid any possible partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @example in string at ./test/capture.pl line 20.
Possible unintended interpolation of @host in string at ./test/capture.pl line 20.
Global symbol "@example" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @example"?) at ./test/capture.pl line 20.
Global symbol "@host" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @host"?) at ./test/capture.pl line 20.
```

Solution is of course quoting, and I found the answer after a lot of googling.

`$line5` is the one giving the `line 20` error.
`$line4` has the answer. The `q()` does single-quotes

```perl
my ($line4) =
q(Message 1A2D2V0L007336 from [20.85.223.71] <> to <user@example.com> with subject 'Postmaster notify: see transcript for details' message-id '<202111021302.1A2D2kq3001573@host.example.com>' date 'Tue, 2 Nov 2021 14:02:46 +0100' infected by {HEX}EICAR.TEST.3.UNOFFICIAL);
my ($line5) =
"Message 1A2D2V0L007336 from [20.85.223.71] <> to <user@example.com> with subject 'Postmaster notify: see transcript for details' message-id '<202111021302.1A2D2kq3001573@host.example.com>' date 'Tue, 2 Nov 2021 14:02:46 +0100' infected by {HEX}EICAR.TEST.3.UNOFFICIAL";
```

Reference: [Strings in Perl: quoted, interpolated and escaped](https://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl)